# how to recommend other contents that created by a node author to a visitor in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I have a commercial website that mades by drupal 7.X . here i want to recommend some of other contents that created by that node author to visitors . i searched a lot but the only thing that I've found is to defining a relation in views to limit user to see his/her own contents . 
is there anybody that has a same problem in drupal 7.X?

Answer (score 0):

Contextual filters in View is the easiest / most correct way to accomplish this task.  You can create a view that defines a block and shows content of the type you are after.  Then by adding a Contextual filter of "Author uid" and selecting the 'provide default value' bullet and choosing User ID from URL, then that block will display content created by that same user.

I can offer you some screenshots if that would help.  Views is most excellent at performing this task IMO